# Primitive data type in C to represent the WORD size of a CPU-arch

Tags: c, memcpy

I observed that size of long is always equal to the WORD size of any given CPU architecture. Is it true for all architectures? I am looking for a portable way to represent a WORD sized variable in C.

Comment: Can you please make your question shorter (maybe move the original into the body of your post) and state your intention in your post, please?

Comment: most modern CPU does fetch from RAM with full cacheline. (64 bytes for intel). Fastest instructions for moving data will be SSE2 load/store.

Comment: @Sandip, what algorithm are you working on? Is it something like memcpy/memmove (or STREAM?).

Comment: @Sandip, Why are you re-implementing `memcpy`?

Comment: @strager: I was looking at a implementation of memcpy in which they check if the buffer and size are both long aligned and then perform a word-by-word copy.

Comment: @Sandip, any good implementation of memcpy will do a align check and try to do a fastest possible way of copying. Not-aligned part can be byte-copied, but the remaining will be copied with prefetch and vector load/store.

Comment: @strager: So how can we find the word size of the given Arch in a portable way? Since we would need that to perform the align check

Comment: @Sandip, try to create a new question with only one topic (Finding of natural alignment in portable way). Or use natural alignment for biggest size (8 or 16 byte)

Answer (score 3):

C doesn't deal with instructions.  In C99, you can copy any size `struct` using an single assignment:

```
struct huge { int data[1 << 20]; };
struct huge a, b;
a = b;
```

With a smart compiler, this should generate the fastest (single-threaded, though in the future hopefully multi-threaded) code to perform the copy.

You can use the `int_fast8_t` type if you want the "fastest possible" integer type as defined by the vendor.  This will likely correspond with the word size, but it's certainly not guaranteed to even be single-instruction-writable.

I think your best option would be to default to one type (e.g. `int`) and use the C preprocessor to optimize for certain CPU's.

Comment: where "int_fast8_t" type is defined? what header? what standard?

Answer (score 3):

No.  In fact, the scalar and vector units often have different word sizes.  And then there are string instructions and built-in DMA controllers with oddball capabilities.

If you want to copy data fast, `memcpy` from the platform's standard C library is usually the fastest.

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows, `sizeof(long)` is 4, even on 64-bit versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

No, standard have no such type (with maximize memory throughput).

But it states that `int` must be fastest type for the processor for doing ALU operations on it.

Comment: C99 6.2.5 says: A "plain" int object has the natural size suggested by the architecture of the execution environment.

Comment: what means "natural" ? from "C99.An economic and cultural commentary"
"
There may be several interpretations of the term `natural` size for some processor architectures. Efficiency is usually a
big consideration. 
The choice of representation ... In some cases it may have already been
specified by a hardware vendor."

Answer (score 1):

I think the nearest answers you'll get are...

- `int` and `unsigned int` often (but not always) match the register width of the machine.
- there's a type which is an integer-the-same-size-as-a-pointer, spelled `intptr_t` and available from stddef.h IIRC. This should obviously match the address-width for your architecture, though I don't know that there's any guarantee.

However, there often really isn't a single word-size for the architecture - there can be registers with different widths (e.g. the "normal" vs. MMX registers in Intel x86), the register width often doesn't match the bus width, addresses and data may be different widths and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Things will get more complicated in embedded world. ASAIK, C51 is 8bit processor but in Keil C for c51, long have 4 bytes. I think it's compiler dependent.

Comment: Probably. Robert Love says in LKD that in Linux, long always represents the word size for all architectures it supports. Read the first 2 paragraphs of this chapter.
http://linuxkernel2.atw.hu/ch19lev1sec2.html